# How can I add a captcha to this HTML form

Tags: forms, captcha

I wanted to add a captcha box to this form. The past developer added this form as html within the content editor.. how can i integrate the captcha to this form? I'm relatively new to drupal and work in wordpress but i am not sure how i can integrate the drupal captcha feature to this form.

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>Name:
            <input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" />
        </p>
        <p>Email:
            <input id="Email" type="text" name="Email" />
        </p>
        <p>Phone:
            <input id="Phone" type="text" name="Phone" />
        </p>
        <p class="antispam">Leave this empty:
            <input type="text" name="url" />
        </p>
        <p>How Can We Help?
            <br />
            <textarea id="Message" name="Message" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
        </p>

        <div class="home-submit-link">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you have two obvious choices :

- either you reimplement the form using the drupal webform module and then add some captcha module like recaptcha,
- or you keep going the tought html-only route and just see how you can integrate a captcha library within your "html within the content editor" form...

I'd say the first strategy is wiser. Particularly since your form is fairly straighforward.

Comment: thanks... just thought there was a way of integrating it into html

Comment: There probably is. It's just that it'll certainly be thougher to integrate a captcha library rather than a ready to use drupal module... But then the choice is yours.

Comment: But having a play with the webform module is certainly worth a go.